# Pandas dataframe to csv rows messing up

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a pandas dataframe, and I am trying to have it exported to a CSV file.

The output file, however, messes up the rows instead of creating a clean file.

So far, I have tried using a different separator such as "/t", and convert values under "fulltext" into a list hoping it would prevent all this mess up.

my code is:

```
    def __toCSV(dataframe, name):
    name = name.replace(' ', '_')
    name = name + '.csv'
    try:
        return dataframe.to_csv(name,encoding='utf-8', index=False)
    except Exception as e:
        print('The object can\'t be converted into a csv file.\n'+e)
    finally:
        if os.path.exists(name):
            print('\033[1m'+ '{}  is succesfully created.'.format(name)+'\033[1m' )
```

dataframe is a pandas df that has three columns, "name", "url", and "fulltext".
name is a string, which is the name of the file to be saved.

This is the CSV output that became all mixed up with rows"
[image: csv export messing up]

This is the desired output, which is clean:
[image: desired output]

When it is in the pandas dataframe, all the rows seem in order. Also, when I export it as JSON, it does not mess up the rows as well.

The problem when I face only occurs, when I try to export it to a CSV.

This is how the data looks in pandas dataframe
[image: How it looks in pd]

What am I doing wrong here? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: have you tried running the function without using return? I.e, change `return dataframe.to_csv(name,encoding='utf-8', index=False)` to `dataframe.to_csv(name,encoding='utf-8', index=False)`

Comment: Are you sure this is a csv issue, not an import issue in excel? What does the csv look like in plain text?

Comment: @PreciXon Thanks, I tried. No help so far.

Comment: @RJAdriaansen I tried opening the file in notepad ++ , still seems all messed up.

Comment: Then try saving it with `to_excel()` and see if it does open correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your spreadsheet software (e.g. Excel) is confused by  `"` or `'` in the cell entries. Is the text looking good if you open it with a text editor?
You could remove the text qualifier you are usig from each cell entry.
For example if you want to open the csv with `"` as your text qualifier.

Remove `"` from each cell entry before saving the df:

```
for index in df.index:
    for column in df.columns:
        cell_entry = df.loc[index, column]
        df.loc[index, column] = cell_entry.replace('"', ' ')
```